# Is there a way to get the parameterised form of Transfer-Function/state-space representation of a RLC circuit in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, state-space, transfer-function, simulink-library

I have a complex circuit at hand, and I want to find the state-space representation (or transfer function) of that MIMO circuit. I followed this article to generate the correct state-space representation for some specific value of resistors and capacitors.

`https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/131093-transfer-function-of-a-simple-circuit-using-simulink`

But, I want to get parameterised form of mathematical equations, so that I can tweak the values of the capacitors and resistors on the go, while doing the simulation. This can be done by hand, but since the model is too complex, the chances of doing some calculation mistake is high.

Thanks in advance for some insights on how to do this.

I am able to get the state-space matrices for fixed values of the capacitors and the inductors, but couldn't find a way to parameterise it using variables. I tried making the variables using realp and sysm, but those data types are not supported by "Linearize" in "Linear Analysis Tool" of Simulink.